# While exporting ssrs report to word, columns are growing horizontally

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

While exporting ssrs report to word, columns are growing horizontally not vertically due to this report alignment is not correct. when same report is exported to pdf working fine. Please help me how to wordwrap text in column while exporting to word.